# A solution in a solved query (about hash table) gives me NaN

Tags: javascript

I was studying the function in the answer below:

[Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array)

but I am saddened to see it doesn't work for me (on repl.it). All the values end up being NaN, no matter how I try to increment them on line 13. What's wrong?

```
function mode(array)
{
    if(array.length === 0)
        return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = array[0], maxCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var el = array[i];
        if(modeMap[el] === null)
                modeMap[el] = 1;
        else
            modeMap[el] = modeMap[el] + 1;  
        if(modeMap[el] > maxCount)
        {
            maxEl = el;
            maxCount = modeMap[el];
        }
    }
    console.log(modeMap)
    return maxEl;
}

mode([4,2,6,2,6,6,6,6,]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of comparing `modeMap[el]=== null` you should check against undefined.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BjVGw5sbQXamOknypnyM?p=preview

```
function mode(array)
{
    if(array.length === 0)
        return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = array[0], maxCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var el = array[i];
        if(modeMap[el] === undefined)
                modeMap[el] = 1;
        else
            modeMap[el] = modeMap[el] + 1; 

        if(modeMap[el] > maxCount)
        {
            maxEl = el;
            maxCount = modeMap[el];
        }
    }
    console.log(modeMap)
    return maxEl;
}

mode([4,2,6,2,6,6,6,6]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is you're triple equals comparing to `null`, when you should be comparing against `undefined`:

```
if (modeMap[el] === undefined)
```

Since `el` isn't in `modeMap`, `modeMap[el]` will be `undefined`, not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are checking strict equality `===` against `null`, while `undefined` is the value returned when you access a non-existent key in an `Object`.

[The robust way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3550319/1400768) to check whether a variable is `undefined` or not is:

```
if (typeof variable === "undefined") {
    // Do something
}
```

Checking against `window.undefined` (with `===`) is not safe for JavaScript versions prior to 1.8.5, where it is **writable**. [It is made **non-writable** from JavaScript version 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).