# Highest occurrence in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, mode

Hi my knowledge on javascript is very limited and basic. Basically below is I will prompt a pop-up that displays the answer to the value. The thing is from the coding I found below if I had to insert an array lets say `1,2,3,2` the output would be `,` since it has the highest occurrence in the array. Is there a way to edit this code so that the answer to the input above would be `2`

I have done my fair share of research:

Here are the links:

- [Highest occurrence in an array or first selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410470/highest-occurrence-in-an-array-or-first-selected/40410898)
- [Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array)
- https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/numbers-only-input-values-in-text-box-how/3029

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function evaluate() {
      var input = prompt("Please enter your input");
      var array = new Array();

     function mode(array)
{
    if(array.length == 0)
        return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = array[0], maxCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var el = array[i];
        if(modeMap[el] == null)
            modeMap[el] = 1;
        else
            modeMap[el]++;  
        if(modeMap[el] > maxCount)
        {
            maxEl = el;
            maxCount = modeMap[el];
        }
    }
    return maxEl;
}
      document.writeln("Your calculation is: ");
      document.writeln(mode(input) + " with a starting input string of: " + input);

    }
  </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    evaluate();
  </script>
```

Comment: Problem is likely in the input function, which you didn't provide..

Comment: sorry i didnt copy it well, lemme ammend it quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert the string `'1,2,3,2'` into the array `[ 1, 2, 3, 2 ]` first. this can be done with the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function. You probably also want to [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) each element in case someone formats them with a space.

```js
function evaluate() {
  const input = prompt("Please enter the array of integers")
    .split(',')
    .map(item => item.trim());

  function mode(items) {
    const counts = items
      .reduce((counts, item) => {
        const currentItemCount = counts.get(item) || 0;
        return counts.set(item, currentItemCount + 1);
      }, new Map());
    const maxEntry = Array.from(counts.entries())
      .reduce((maxEntry, entry) => {
        return entry[1] > maxEntry[1] ? entry : maxEntry;
      });
    return maxEntry[0];
  }
  
  document.writeln("Your calculation is: ");
  document.writeln(mode(input) + " with a starting input string of: " + input);
}

evaluate();
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated ^.^

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from the fact that you never convert your input (which you receive from `prompt` as a string) into an actual array.

When `mode` is called directly on the string, the comma is returned as being the most common because comma *is* the most common character in the string.

To fix this, you need to convert your string into an actual array so you're operating on the elements of the array instead of the characters of the string.

You can use the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to split your string (`"1,2,3,2"`) at commas into an array (`["1", "2", "3", "2"]`) which you can then pass to the mode function:

```
mode(input.split(","))
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated ^.^