# Get lowest frequency in array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, frequency, find-occurrences

I am making a random letters generator. It has to find a given word in the least amount of tries. It lists the number of tries everytime in an array. I want to get the least frequent value in the array.

I already got the most frequent value to work with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31227768/5288019)

I tried this for lowest frequency but it doesn't work and gives me the last item, with 1 occurence everytime :

```
var mif = 1;
var itemin;
if (m <= mif) {
    mif = m;
    itemin = generations[i];
}
```

Comment: What does this code do?

Comment: creates a minimal frequency variable, and a variable to store the item that has the lowest frequency, then (with the for loop from the post I linked), check if the count of each item is equal or smaller than the minimial frequency and if it is, change the minimal frequency to m (count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your var with a bigger value :

```js
var arr1 = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];
var mif = 99999999999999;
var m = 0;
var itemin;
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    if (arr1[i] == arr1[j])
      m++;
  }
  if (mif > m) {
    mif = m;
    itemin = arr1[i];
  }
  console.log(arr1[i] + ' exist ' + m + ' times in array');
  m = 0;
}
console.log('item less frequent : ' + itemin);
```