# Detect the selected month in Angular UI bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

I'm using the [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) datepicker in day mode for my project. How can I get the currently open month befoure the new date was selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time trying to find the right way to get this, and upon reading the datepicker directive and controller's source code, I couldn't find a non-dirty way of getting the current month, so here's a very hacky way to do it.

**Warning, future versions of Angular-UI Bootstrap might break this approach**

You will need to use [AngularJS decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) for this. Here's the code you'll need:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
  .config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('datepickerDirective', function($delegate) {
      var directive = $delegate[0];
      //get a copy of the directive's original compile function
      var directiveCompile = directive.compile;

      //overwrite the original compile function
      directive.compile = function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        // call the directive's compile with apply to send the original 'this' and arguments to it
        var link = directiveCompile.apply(this, arguments);

        //here's where the magic starts
        return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
          //call the original link
          link.apply(this, arguments);
          //move is the internal function called when you click
          //on the chevrons for previous and next month
          var originalMove = scope.move;
          scope.move = function(direction) {
            originalMove.apply(this, arguments);
            //when move is called, the 'this' object contains a 'title' property with the current month!
            var currentMonth = this.title;
            //emit the event to parent scopes
            scope.$emit('datepicker.monthChanged', currentMonth);
          }
        }
      };

      return $delegate;
    });
  })
```

And then your controller can listen to `datepicker.monthChanged`:

```
$scope.$on('datepicker.monthChanged', function(event, newVal) {
  $scope.currentMonth = newVal;
})
```

Since the datepicker controller doesn't keep the current selected date within the `$scope`, it keeps it in a closure variable, the only way I found you could get the selected month was in the `this` object when the function `move` is called. `move` is called whenever you click on the previous and next month icons.

Here's a plunkr demonstrating the usage of this decorator: http://plnkr.co/edit/iWJWjM8nCsh5TMupNioo?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is absolutely full answer! )) More than I could expect ))

Comment: Since you've already studied the topic, could you please help me with another datepicker functionality extension related question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32676310/601726

Comment: I'm trying to use this aproach, but I'm getting "Unknown provider: datepickerDirectiveProvider" error, any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

You should use ng-model to assign the selected value to a variable. If you use a raw scope variable, you'd be able to access the Date object at any time. e.g.:

```
<input ng-model="selectedDate" other-datepicker-directives />
```

Then in your controller, the selectedDate value is a Date object, to which you can access the normal date properties; like .getMonth(). If you then use a watch, you can have a local variable always set with the currently selected month!

So, in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.selectedDate }, function()
{
    // bail out if no selected date
    if (!angular.isDefined($scope.selectedDate)) return;

    $scope.selectedMonth = $scope.selectedDate.getMonth();
});
```

Now whenever $scope.selectedDate gets changed, $scope.selectedMonth will be updated. This means you could display the selected month in your HTML view like so:

<span> Selected Month: {{selectedMonth}}</span>

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works when the date has already been selected, the question asks how to get the open month before the date is selected.

Comment: @yvesmancera is quite right. I'm trying to get the displayed month (part of the rendered datepicker template), not the selected date month.

Comment: Ahh good point - I missed that. Doesn't look like something that could be gotten easily... there's a scope variable "title" in the datepicker view that would have the month in it when in day-view mode... Something like:
angular.element(".yourElementSelectorWithDatePickerDirective").controller("DatePicker"). That would give you the controller for the DatePicker and then the Title of the child directive (Day picker) may be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
  * 从一维数组中选出出现次数最多的项
  * @param {Array} arr - 一维数组
  * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20762472/5819157
  */
function getMaxOccurrence(arr) {
    var arrMap = {},
      maxCount = 0,
      maxEl,
      item;

    var index = 0,
      length = arr.length;

    for (; index < length; index++) {
      if (arr.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        item = arr[index];
        arrMap.hasOwnProperty(item) ? ++arrMap[item] : (arrMap[item] = 1);
        if (arrMap[item] > maxCount) {
          maxCount = arrMap[item];
          maxEl = item;
        }
      }
    }

    return maxEl;
}
```

```js
$scope.datetimeOption = {
  customClass: getDayClass,
  showWeeks: false,
}
```

```js
var tempYear = null;
var prevStartOfMonth = null;
var tempMonthMap = [];

function getDayClass(data) {
  var date = data.date;
  var mode = data.mode;

  var selectedMonth = null;
  var selectedDate = null;
  var startOfMonth = null;
  var endOfMonth = null;

  if (tempMonthMap.length === 42) {
    tempMonthMap = [];
  }

  if (mode === 'day') {
    if (date.getMonth) {
      tempMonthMap.push(moment(date).month());
    }

    if (tempMonthMap.length === 42) {
      tempYear = moment(date).year();

      selectedMonth = getMaxOccurrence(tempMonthMap);

      selectedDate = moment({ year: tempYear, month: selectedMonth });
      startOfMonth = moment(selectedDate).startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      endOfMonth = moment(selectedDate).endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

      if (prevStartOfMonth !== startOfMonth) {
        getListRequest({ since: startOfMonth, until: endOfMonth });
        prevStartOfMonth = startOfMonth;
      }
    }

      //

  }

  return '';
}
```