# Attach click event for the weekday labels in Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) datepicker with the [gm.datepickerMultiSelect](https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect) extension and I'd like to make weekdays labels clickable, so that I could select all days in the month (like all Wednesdays). I can get/calculate all days of the same weekday and add them to the selected days scope, but as I'm rather new to AngularJS & Bootstrap UI, I can't find the right way to trigger that click event for the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular UI Bootstrap lets you override their directive's templates. You can create your own template by putting it inside a `<script>` tag with type `text/ng-template`.

So we copy the contents of Angular UI's [`template/datepicker/day.html`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/datepicker/day.html) and we alter it a little bit to call a new function `selectWeekday` on our weekday's `ng-click` :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/datepicker/day.html">
  <table role="grid" aria-labelledby="{{::uniqueId}}-title" aria-activedescendant="{{activeDateId}}">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
        </th>
        <th colspan="{{::5 + showWeeks}}">
          <button id="{{::uniqueId}}-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="toggleMode()" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" tabindex="-1" style="width:100%;"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center"></th>
        <!-- Added ng-click and style -->
        <th ng-click="selectWeekday(label)" style="cursor:pointer;" ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center"><small aria-label="{{::label.full}}">{{::label.abbr}}</small></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
        <td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6"><em>{{ weekNumbers[$index] }}</em></td>
        <td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center" role="gridcell" id="{{::dt.uid}}" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
          <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}">{{::dt.label}}</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

**Note**: This script tag must be within your `ng-app` or else it will be ignored and won't overwrite the original template.

Now we need to modify the `datepicker` directive with [AngularJS decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) to add the `selectWeekday` function:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'gm.datepickerMultiSelect'
  ])
  .config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('datepickerDirective', function($delegate) {
      var directive = $delegate[0];
      //get a copy of the directive's original compile function
      var directiveCompile = directive.compile;

      //overwrite the original compile function
      directive.compile = function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        // call the directive's compile with apply to send the original 'this' and arguments to it
        var link = directiveCompile.apply(this, arguments);

        //here's where the magic starts
        return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
          //call the original link
          link.apply(this, arguments);

          scope.selectWeekday = function(label) {
            scope.$emit('datepicker.selectWeekday', label);
          };

        };
      };

      return $delegate;
    });
  })
```

And from the controller listen to `datepicker.selectWeekday`:

```
.controller('DateController', function($scope) {

  $scope.$on('datepicker.selectWeekday', function(event, newVal) {
    $scope.selectedWeekday = newVal;
  });

});
```

From here you can add the logic to select the days based on the known selected weekday!

Here's a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ef4gd7SUYMcG05PuvqFh?p=preview