# Popular word in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the most popular/common word from an Array, I've tried the following but instead of it just saying 'Rain' it displays this inside the console instead [rain: 2, hot: 1].

What am I doing wrong? I only want to display the number one most popular words without the number.

Any help/advice would be helpful, thank you.

```
  var defaultArray = [{age:"25-35",country:"united kingdom",sex:"male",word:"rain"},{age:"25-35",country:"united arab emirates",sex:"male",word:"hot"},{age:"25-35",country:"zimbabwe",sex:"female",word:"rain"}];

  /* Popular */
  function popular() {
    var words = [];
    for(var p = 0; p < defaultArray.length; p++){
      var word = defaultArray[p].word;
      words.push(word);
      console.log(words);
    }
    var count = [];
    for (var i = 0, j = words.length; i < j; i++) {
      if (count[words[i]]) {
        count[words[i]]++;
      }
      else {
        count[words[i]] = 1;
      }
    }
    console.log(count);
  }
  popular();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in keeping with the original functionality you had. you could just tweak it a bit to get the most popular word. NB: this does not account for ties.

```
var defaultArray = [
  {age:"25-35",country:"united arab emirates",sex:"male",word:"hot"},
  {age:"25-35",country:"united kingdom",sex:"male",word:"rain"},
  {age:"25-35",country:"united arabemirates",sex:"male",word:"hot"}];

/* Popular */
function popular() {
  var count = 0
  var max=0;
  var currentword="";
  var words = [];

  for(var p = 0; p < defaultArray.length; p++){
    var word = defaultArray[p].word;
    words.push(word);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i<words.length; i++) {
    if (max<=count){
      max=count;    
    }
    count=0;
    for (var x=0; x<words.length; x++)
    {
      if (words[i]==words[x] ){
        count++;
      }
      if (count>max)currentword=words[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(currentword);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to loop through the count array and find the word with the highest count:

```
var mostCommonWordCount = 0;
var mostCommonWord = "";
for (var key in count) {
    if (count[key] > mostCommonWordCount) {
        mostCommonWordCount = count[key]
        mostCommonWord = key;
    }
}
console.log(mostCommonWord);
```

After this runs, `mostCommonWord` will contain the word with the highest count.  The only caveat is that if there are multiple words with 3 occurrences, for example, then the first one in the `count` array is the one that will be assigned to `mostCommonWord`.  So if you're wanting something that will return multiple words if they all have the same count, you'd need to modify this a bit.

Disclaimer: There is likely a better way to do this, but this is the first thing I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove almost everything after you create an array of words and instead add this function:

```
function mostPopularWord(arr){
  return arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return arr.filter(function(v){ return v===a }).length -
        arr.filter(function(v){ return v===b }).length
  }).pop();
}
```

Then pass it your array of words like:

```
mostPopularWord(words) // Returns rain
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y657uz6d/1/)

I did not write that function, I found it when searching for a way to help. You can read more about what you were trying to do here: [Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

for counting and groupping you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, like this:

```js
var defaultArray = [{
    age: "25-35",
    country: "united kingdom",
    sex: "male",
    word: "rain"
  }, {
    age: "25-35",
    country: "united arab emirates",
    sex: "male",
    word: "hot"
  }, {
    age: "25-35",
    country: "zimbabwe",
    sex: "female",
    word: "rain"
  }];

  /* Popular */
  function popular(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
      if (!acc[cur.word]) acc[cur.word] = 0;
      acc[cur.word] += 1;
      if (acc.MaxCount < acc[cur.word]) {
        acc.MaxCount = acc[cur.word];
        acc.PopularWord = cur.word;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {
      MaxCount: 0
    }).PopularWord;
  }
  document.write('Max popular word: ',popular(defaultArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend a JavaScript utility library like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/), in which case you could do something like this:

```
var obj = _.countBy(_.map(defaultArray, 'word'));
console.log(obj); // Object {rain: 2, hot: 1}

var word = _.keys(obj).reduce(function (a,b) { return obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b });
console.log(word); // "rain"
```

*Note: See other answers for plain JavaScript functionality*