# js Page Freezing on from .length?

Tags: javascript, html

This function is freezing my page.

```
function findMode (array)
{
    var modeArr = [];
    var modeCounter = [];
    modeArr.length = array.length;
    modeCounter.length = array.length;
}
```

However, when I remove this it runs just fine.

```
        modeArr.length = array.length;
        modeCounter.length = array.length;
```

Here is all of my code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p> Please enter a series of numbers, each separated by a new line.<br><p>

<textarea id="myTextArea" rows = "7" cols = "50"></textarea><br>

<button onclick="processData()">Done</button>

<p id = "mean"></p>
<p id = "median"></p>
<p id = "count"></p>
<p id = "summation"></p>
<p id = "mode"></p>
<p id = "variance"></p>
<p id = "sd"></p>

<script type = "text/javascript">

        var mean = 0;
        var median = 0;
        var count = length;
        var mode = 0;
        var variance = 0;
        var standard_deviation = 0;

        var meanOutput = document.getElementById('mean'); 
        var medianOutput = document.getElementById('median'); 
        var modeOutput = document.getElementById('mode'); 
        var countOutput = document.getElementById('count'); 
        var summationOutput = document.getElementById('summation'); 
        var varianceOutput = document.getElementById('variance'); 
        var sdOutput = document.getElementById('sd'); 

    function processData()
    {
        var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value.split('\n');

        var sum = findSum(arrayOfLines);
        findMean(arrayOfLines, sum);
        findMedian(arrayOfLines);
        findMode(arrayOfLines);
        findVariance(arrayOfLines);
        findStandardDeviation(arrayOfLines);
        findVariance(arrayOfLines);
    }

    function findSum (array)
    {
        var count = array.length;
        var sum = 0;

        for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
        {
            sum += parseInt(array[a]);
        }

        countOutput.innerHTML = "Count: " + array.length; 
        summationOutput.innerHTML = "Sum: " + JSON.stringify(sum); 
        return sum;
    }

    function findMode (array)
    {
        var modeArr = [];
        var modeCounter = [];
        modeArr.length = array.length;
        modeCounter.length = array.length;

        for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
        {   
            for (var b = 0; b < modeArr.length; b++)
            {
                if (modeArr[a] == modeArr[b])
                {
                    modeCounter[a]++;
                }

                if (a == 0)
                {
                    b--;
                }
            }

            modeArr[a] = array[a];
        }

        modeOutput.innerHTML = "Mode: "; 

    }


    function findMean (array, sum)
    {
        mean = sum/array.length;
        meanOutput.innerHTML = "Mean: " +  mean.toPrecision(2); 

    }




    function findMedian (array)
    {
        for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            array[i] = +array[i];
        }

        var sortedArrayOfLines = array.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});

        if (array.length % 2 == 1)
        {
            median = sortedArrayOfLines[((array.length - 1)/2)]
        }

        else        
        {
            median = (sortedArrayOfLines[array.length/2] + sortedArrayOfLines[(array.length/2)+1])/2
        }

        medianOutput.innerHTML = "Median: " + median; 
    }

    function findVariance (array) 
    {
        var mean = mean(array);
        return mean(array.map(function(num) 
        {
            varianceOutput.innerHTML = Math.pow(num - mean, 2); 
        }));
    }

    function findStandardDeviation (array) 
    {
        medianOutput.innerHTML = Math.sqrt(variance(array)); 

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `array`? How are you calling the function?

Comment: Check your browser console. Are there any errors?

Comment: It is an array of numbers taken from a textarea. I am sure it is full.

Comment: @Sidney The whole page freezes, it is impossible to check errors.

Comment: The whole browser tab freezes? You can't open the console with `F12`? (Assuming you're on a Windows computer using Chrome)

Comment: Please post the rest of the code

Comment: @Sidney Ok, I have.

Comment: @Parker How big is `array`?

Comment: Can you cut it down to only the parts that matter to your question? `var mean = mean(array);` won’t work, so it’s apparently not being run and can therefore be removed.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue isn't the `length` it's a infinite loop.

The problem is this bit of code

```
if (a == 0)
{
  b--;
}
```

This is inside the following loop with `b` as the iterator. See below.

```
for (var b = 0; b < modeArr.length; b++)
```

`a` is set to zero by the outer loop. Thus `a==0` is always true inside the inner loop. `b` will never increase only *decrease*. Thus this is a infinite loop because `b` will never be greater than `modeArr.length`.

So I would consider revising the function, below is a example of a possible candidate for a mode function:

[Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Parker Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.