# How do we get the most different value from object and print out the key of the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an object like this

```
{ '1': 2, 
  '2': 2, 
  '4': 2, 
  '5': 2, 
  '-2': 2, 
  '-1': 1 
}
```

Yeah we know, that the most different value from it is '1'

So the function will print out the keys from the object '-1'

Which function to find the key?

It takes about a few hours and I still not found it, because the object is a string

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: what do you mean by ```most different```? do you mean exist in least number as in there are 5 twos and 1 one(s) in your example?

Comment: i've edited formatting

Comment: I mean, the object -1 has the value 1, and it's the most different right?. What the question is, how to get the -1

Comment: thanks @Miro , it help for clearing the question, can you also help with the solution too?

Comment: I think this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917849/how-to-get-least-frequent-item-of-array-javascript

Comment: your question needs more clarification as what happens when you have two or more ones or is it always just one that's different than the rest? What's the bigger purpose?

Comment: @JensvanGroeningen thanks for giving an advice, did you know how to get it, when it using object not array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to iterate twice over the object to first find the least frequent and then get the key of the resulting value. There may be an easier way that I don't know about.

```js
let obj = { '1': 2, 
  '2': 2, 
  '4': 2, 
  '5': 2, 
  '-2': 2, 
  '-1': 1 
}


function leastFrequentObjKey(obj) {
    var dict = {};
    Object.values(obj).forEach(val => {
        if (!dict[val]) dict[val] = 0;
        dict[val]++;
    });
    
    var value = Math.min.apply(null, Object.values(dict));
    return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] == value );
}



console.log( leastFrequentObjKey(obj) );
```

Comment: you are really kind Miro, oh I see, that we can iterate two times inside object. Thanks

Comment: @theDreamer911 check the edit - single function only

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` method on `Object.keys` should simplify.

```js
let obj = { 1: 2, 2: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, "-2": 2, "-1": 1 };

const res = Object.keys(obj).reduce((min, key) =>
  obj[min] > obj[key] ? key : min
);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: this finds the smallest value. OP wants least frequent

Comment: @Miro, It is getting the least frequent (least value)'s corresponding key, which is '-1' in this case right?

Comment: It just happens to work in this case. However if `1:-5` and `2:-5` it will return 1. He wants the least frequent -- not just the lowest.