# How can I find the top n occurrences of an object value in an array using Typescript/JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, find-occurrences

Using TypeScript I have an array of objects which may contain the same values as other objects in the array. The following array, for example, contains objects that have the value "intent". I would like the find the top 3 most commonly occurring intents:

```
[
  {
    "intent": "hello",
    "other_value": "blah"
  },
  {
    "intent": "hello",
    "other_value": "blahblah"
  },
  {
    "intent": "hi",
    "other_value": "anothervalue"
  },
  {
    "intent": "hello",
    "other_value": "what?"
  },
  {
    "intent": "hello",
    "other_value": "eh?"
  },
  {
    "intent": "hi",
    "other_value": "okthen"
  },
  {
    "intent": "yo",
    "other_value": "alright"
  },
  {
    "intent": "hi",
    "other_value": "yes"
  },
  {
    "intent": "yo",
    "other_value":"yawhat?"
  },
  {
    "intent": "hey",
    "other_value": "meh"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get some sort of result that will easily show me the top 3, maybe a key/value pair array or something:

```
[
  {
    "intent": "hello",
    "occurrences": 4
  },
  {
    "intent": "hi",
    "occurrences": 3
  },
  {
    "intent": "yo",
    "occurrences": 2
  }
]
```

Below is my attempt at a solution:

```
function top3(array) {
    let results = [];
    array.forEach(item => {
        if (results[item.intent] != null) {
          results[item.intent] += 1
        } else {
          results[item.intent] = 1;
        }
    });

    results = results.sort();
    return results.slice(0, 3);
}
```

However this only returns an array of the occurrence values and not the name of the intent themselves. So I am struggling to find with the array which value belongs to which intent.

I tried following the answers posted in this solution:

[Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array)

However, I couldn't figure out how to find `n` occurrences, instead just the top occurrence. I wasn't sure how to use that logic to carry on to find the next few occurrences.

Comment: Are you look for any answer or a "best" answer? Easiest would be to use the algorithm you found for returning most occurring element, delete the most occurring element from the list, then re-run the algorithm. This question would be more helpful if you first attempted a solution and provided code- then we could guide you from there.

Comment: Create a counter for intents and sort it desc, there should be a lot of similar questions. Also, you don't show any attempt.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include my attempt at a solution. Please consider your removing your down-votes if my question is now of satisfactory standard. Thanks. @AdamS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get an object with the count first by building an array of objects, sort it descending by `occurences` and slice the array for getting top three elements only.

```js
var data = [{ intent: "hello", other_value: "blah" }, { intent: "hello", other_value: "blahblah" }, { intent: "hi", other_value: "anothervalue" }, { intent: "hello", other_value: "what?" }, { intent: "hello", other_value: "eh?" }, { intent: "hi", other_value: "okthen" }, { intent: "yo", other_value: "alright" }, { intent: "hi", other_value: "yes" }, { intent: "yo", other_value: "yawhat?" }, { intent: "hey", other_value: "meh" }],
    count = data
        .reduce((r, { intent }) => {
            r[intent] = r[intent] || { intent, occurences: 0 };
            r[intent].occurences++;
            return r;
        }, {}),
    top3 = Object
        .values(count)
        .sort((a, b) => b.occurences - a.occurences)
        .slice(0, 3);
    
console.log(top3);
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Despite all the downvotes I received for this, people still managed to post decent answers. Thanks for your efforts. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create such groups:

```js
const source = [{"intent":"hello","other_value":"blah"},{"intent":"hello","other_value":"blahblah"},{"intent":"hi","other_value":"anothervalue"},{"intent":"hello","other_value":"what?"},{"intent":"hello","other_value":"eh?"},{"intent":"hi","other_value":"okthen"},{"intent":"yo","other_value":"alright"},{"intent":"hi","other_value":"yes"},{"intent":"yo","other_value":"yawhat?"},{"intent":"hey","other_value":"meh"}];

const g = source.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(!acc[item.intent]) {
    acc[item.intent] = 0;
  }
  
  acc[item.intent]++;
  return acc;
}, {});

let top3 = Object.entries(g).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]).slice(0, 3);

console.log('groups', g);
console.log('top 3', top3);
```

You may further convert the *top 3* collection to corresponding objects using `Array#map`, like this:

```
top3.map(item => { [item[0]]: item[1] });
```