# JavaScript Object as counter not incrementing

Tags: javascript, object, counter

I'm trying to use objects as a counter in JavaScript, to find the most repeated letter in a word, but somehow the function is not working as I intend to. For example, when I call `findMaxRepeatCountInWord('expected')`, the letterCount object ends up with a value of `{ e: 1, x: 1, p: 1, c: 1, t: 1, d: 1 }`. What's wrong with my code? Shouldn't e has a value of 3?

My code:

```
function findMaxRepeatCountInWord(word){
  var letterCount = {};
  word.split('').map(function(v){
    if(letterCount[v] != true){ letterCount[v] = 1 } 
    else(letterCount[v] ++)
  });
  return Object.values(letterCount).sort((a,b) => b-a)[0]
}

findMaxRepeatCountInWord('expected')
```

Comment: It's not....I tried changing the condition within the else{} statement to 'console.log(v)' and it worked fine - it would print out 'e' twice. So the function definitely flew into the else{} statement, I just don't understand why the action within is not implemented.

Comment: But there are three `e`s. It counts 1, 2, 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats another version of JS  comparison fun:

```
 console.log(
   0 != true, // true
   1 != true, // false
   2 != true // true
   3 != true // true
);
```

If you compare a number and a boolean, the boolean is turned into a number (0 -> false, 1 -> true) then equality comparison is done, and therefore only `1` equals `true`. 
Therefore if it reaches `2`, it will enter the first branch again and reset the counter to `1`.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work the way you are hoping:

```
 if(letterCount[v] != true)
```

Try testing with `!hasOwnProperty` (and using forEach instead of map) instead:

```js
function findMaxRepeatCountInWord(word){
    var letterCount = {};
    word.split('').forEach(function(v){
      if(!letterCount.hasOwnProperty(v)){ letterCount[v] = 1 } 
      else letterCount[v] ++
    });
    console.log("letter counts", letterCount)
    return Object.values(letterCount).sort((a,b) => b-a)[0]
  }
  
  console.log(findMaxRepeatCountInWord('expected'))
```

You can also save the cost of a sort with:

```
return Math.max(...Object.values(letterCount))
```

Comment: Not always ... only for 1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I don't think the `Math.max` function works for an array of number though does it?

Comment: @rhea.rao it does

Comment: @rhea.rao `Object.values(letterCount)` returns an array or numbers which is spread to `Math.max`.

Comment: `Math.max(1,2,3)` would return `3`, but `Math.max([1,2,3])` would return `NaN`

Comment: @rhea.rao what about `Math.max(...[1,2,3])` (note the dots aka [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the property as follow: `if (v in letterCount)` this is the most reliable way to check if a key is a property of an object.

*This approach returns the built object*

```js
function findMaxRepeatCountInWord(word) {
  var letterCount = {};
  word.split('').map(function(v) {
    letterCount[v] = (letterCount[v] || 0) + 1;
  });
  
  return letterCount;
}

console.log(findMaxRepeatCountInWord('expected'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Aside note, using the function `Array.prototype.map` is not the best way to solve this problem because you're creating an unnecessary array.

*Alternative approach using the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to group the letters*

```js
function findMaxRepeatCountInWord(word) {
  return word.split('').reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, Object.create(null));
}

console.log(findMaxRepeatCountInWord('expected'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, apart from the if-condition:
`if(letterCount[v] != true)`.

**The solution:**
You can fix the problem easily by just changing the condition to the following:
`if(letterCount[v] == undefined)`

**The problem:**
The condition works as you intended when:

- `letterCount[v]` is `undefined`
- `letterCount[v]` is `1`

But when `letterCount[v]` becomes greater than 1, the condition is true again, because `2 != true` is `true`. For this reason your code will reset the values to `1` every time it has been encountered an odd number of times.

To illustrate, if we run your code on a word with only two `e`'s, we obtain:

```
findMaxRepeatCountInWord('expectd')
> 2
```

but if there is a third occurrence of the letter, as in your example, the number will be reset to `1`.

**Performance**
Nevertheless, this approach is not computationally very efficient. For some discussion regarding efficient solutions of an analogous problem, you may want to give e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array) a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findMaxRepeatCountInWord(word){
  var letterCount = {};
  word.split('').map(function(v){
    if(letterCount[v]==undefined){ letterCount[v]= 1 ;
} 
    else{letterCount[v]=letterCount[v]+1}
  });
  return Object.values(letterCount).sort((a,b) => b-a)[0]
}

var x=findMaxRepeatCountInWord('expected');
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score -1):

The `if` should be:

```
if(!letterCount[v]){ letterCount[v] = 1 } 
else {letterCount[v]++}
```

To keep the code minimally modified. Other answers polish it more.

---

Applied to the OP code:

```js
function findMaxRepeatCountInWord(word){
  var letterCount = {};
  word.split('').map(function(v){
    if(!letterCount[v]){ letterCount[v] = 1 } 
    else(letterCount[v] ++)
  });
  console.log(letterCount)
  return Object.values(letterCount).sort((a,b) => b-a)[0]
}

findMaxRepeatCountInWord('super expected');
```

Comment: using `{}` for `if/else` is not mandatory although it is best practice

Comment: Right, but the original code has parenthesis in place of brackets, which is important to change too.

Comment: Not really...is ugly but valid

Comment: Hm you're right. Works like a expression grouping ? The main issue was the `if` indeed.

Comment: sorry this is not correct, 0 == false, 1 == true, 2 == false, so when we count to 2, `letterCount[v]` would be assigned the value of 1 again, see the answers above