# finding the most common string in array fails with 2 elements or equal amounts

Tags: javascript

I'm using this algorithm to find the most common string in an array the only problem is when an array contains two elements or equals amounts of strings the following method does not work exp: (`arr["Test","Test2"]`) returns nothing

```
Arr["Test", "Test", "Test","Test2"]
//Should return "Test"

  _correctName(array) {
 const modeMap = {};

let maxElement = "";
let maxCount = 1;

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const element = array[i];
  if (modeMap[element] == null)
    modeMap[element] = 1;
  else
    modeMap[element]++;
  if (modeMap[element] > maxCount) {
    maxElement = element;
    maxCount = modeMap[element];
  }
}
 return maxElement;
};
```

Comment: please sample inputs and expected output

Comment: are you trying to get duplicate string from array or common substring?

Comment: done and common string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you started `maxCount` with `1`.

If each element in your array appears only once, then none of them will overpass the initial `1` value.

Try again with `maxCount` starting with `0`.