# Is it possible to get the most common elements in an array and their frequency in a linear amount of time?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a very large array (around 50 000 elements, consisting of single words). I would like to be able to get the most commonly used words, and their frequency in the shortest possible time. The problem with my current method is that:

- 25 elements takes 0 seconds
- 250 elements takes 0 seconds
- 2 500 elements takes 1 second
- 25 000 elements takes 30 seconds
- 50 000 elements takes a minute and a half.

It's not hard to see, that this goes up exponentially, and I'm pretty sure that is because of my method. So my question is whether it is possible to do this in a linear amount of time. The result can be any data format, array of objects, or one object,

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: where is the algorithm *you* are currently using?

Comment: @mplungjan [javascript - Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array) is more specific in this case.

Comment: @user202729 I added it to the list of dupes