# How to find the most occuring item in an array JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter, state

I have an array of objects which contain a "location" key. I already filtered and mapped the events array to a new visitedlocations array so that it only contains the locations. Now I can't figure out how to filter out the most occuring item in the visitedLocations array. Anyone have an idea?

How i filtered the events array:

```
 const visitedLocations = state.events
    .filter((event) => event.timeline.startDate < today)
    .map((event) => {
      return event.location;
    });
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements

Comment: @hoddypeak I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into the answer ? Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 1, 1, 2]
const unique = [...new Set(arr)] // Get unique values/keys
const counts = unique.map(key => (  // Make ojects with each key's count in original array
     {
       'key' : key,
       'count': arr.filter(element => element === key).length 
     } 
  ))
const sorted = counts.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count) // Sort array based on counts
const mostOccurring = sorted[0] // Get first (largest) value

console.log('Unique: ', unique)
console.log('Counts: ', counts)
console.log('Sorted: ', sorted)
console.log('Most occuring: ', mostOccurring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const data = ['location 1', 'location 1', 'location 1', 'location 1', 'location 1', 'location 3', 'location 5', 'location 5'];

function freq(locationArr) {
  return locationArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = -~acc[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

// Convert object into a 2D array.
const arr = Object.entries(freq(data));

// Now sorting the array based on the first index values. 
const sortedResult = arr.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

console.log(sortedResult[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the answer given by **Matthew Flaschen** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array#answer-1053865).

No need to use `map`, `sort`, `reduce` or `filter` functions.

It could be achieved using single `for` loop and couple of `if...else` statements.

Below given approach should be O(n).

```js
function mostFrequentLocations(array)
{
    if(!array.length) return null;

    let modeMap = {};
    let maxEl = array[0];
    let maxCount = 1;

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        let el = array[i];

        if(modeMap[el] === null) modeMap[el] = 1;

        else modeMap[el]++;
  
        if(modeMap[el] > maxCount)
        {
            maxEl = el;
            maxCount = modeMap[el];
        }
    }

    return maxEl;
}
```