# How to find the most frequent character in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

So, I need to write a code where I print the most frequent character in an array. If there is, only one then just print that character, if there are 2 then print both and if there are none then print no number is missing. I have got it to find the most single frequent value, but I can't figure out how to make it print if there are more than one frequent characters.

```
public class ArrayOfNumbers {

    public static void main (String []args) {
        int [] array = {2,3,5,1,2,3};
        int n = 6;
        System.out.println(findMostFrequent);
    }

    public static int findMostFrequent(n, array) {
        int counter = 1;
        int tempCounter;
        int mostFrequent = array{0};
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            temp = a{1};
            tempCounter = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (temp == a[j]){
                tempCount++
            }
            if (tempCounter > counter){
                mostFrequent = temp;
                counter = tempCounter;
            }
        }
        return mostFrequent;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile - multiple errors. Please fix the compile errors and then describe the current behavior.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545590/java-find-the-most-popular-element-in-int-array

Answer (score 1):

Your code has lot's of mistakes!

- Getting the nth item of array is not with `a{1}` but with `a[0]`
- Parsing this value to `int` and not to `int[]` (it's a single value)
- This calling is wrong `System.out.println(findMostFrequent);`. There are parameters missing
- Variable `tempCount` has not been initialized in the findMostFrequent method.
- You don't need the lenght variable `int n` at all. You get the array size by `array.length`.
- Bad copying from [Java - Find the most popular element in int[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545590/java-find-the-most-popular-element-in-int-array)