# find the most popular element in int array in java array {2,3,4,2,3,3,2,9,5}

Tags: java

how can I write a method and return 2 and 3?

I have used Map and it prints 2 but 3.

find the most popular element in int array in java array {2,3,4,2,3,3,2,9,5}

Comment: most popular i.e. most frequent ?

Comment: without seeing your code it is impossible to guess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630727/counting-repeated-elements-in-an-integer-array <-- Could do something like that, and then stream filter it to get the highest results?

Comment: Similar question has been asked previously, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545590/find-the-most-popular-element-in-int-array