# Which is more efficient "Dictionary" or "Tries" for performing the search in string array?

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, hash, trie

I am working on one problem "Most frequent word in an array of strings" and got confused to understand which will be more efficient solution: a trie or a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary is sufficient.

A trie is useful if you're searching for word prefixes, like you want all words that start with "ca": "car", "cat", etc. It won't help if you're not doing something prefix-related.

Comment: Is there any performance cost associated if we have more elements in array in case of dictionary ? I was referring to the following article which uses hashing and min heap approach for the same:  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185697/the-most-efficient-way-to-find-top-k-frequent-words-in-a-big-word-sequence"?

Comment: If the dictionary is a hash table then adding and searching are amortized constant time operations: that means fast. If you need help writing the program I recommend you give it a shot and then post another question with your code.

Comment: Printing the *k* most frequent words is more complicated than printing the single most frequent word and benefits from a more sophisticated algorithm / data structure.